# Soundcloud Widgets - Tabbed by genre?

Tags: widget, soundcloud

I need to create a widget for my website that has tabs at the top depending on genre. I've seen it on a site (www.unseen-music.com) but wondering if it's a website developing thing or whether it is possible to do it solely through the soundcloud widgets?

Comment: You need to be familiar with a coding language and use an API to style this. CSS would probably cut it.

Comment: https://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets doesn't have any UI for changing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create sets with songs filtered by genre, embed these sets as widgets and then style them to be part of tabs.

Or you could indeed use a programming language and retrieve sounds by genre from the API. Then you could build a UI for playing these sounds and it could have tabs – that would not use Widget API at all, but would use HTTP API and possibly if you want some of the SDKs.